# Android Studio 2.0 Upgrade Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0

I upgraded to Android Studio 2.0 and for some reason cannot resolve this issue

```
Error:Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0.
Required by:
    Code:app:unspecified

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
```

Open Android SDK Manager

I have the latest version of the support library as well as previous versions, I have deleted the build folder and rebuilt without success. Here is my complete build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domain.appname"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

And here is the SDK Tools installed
[image]

Gradle Version: 2.11
ANdrud Plugin Version: 2.0.0

How can I resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0. ?

Edit
Project build.gradel

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Please also paste your project level build.gradle

Comment: Added project level build.gradle

Comment: first File -> Invalidate caches and restart and then clean and build after sync ur gradle

Comment: Thank you, I am still getting Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0

Comment: Check if your Android sdk folder have 23.3.0 :     Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7   if not just uninstall all your 'Android Support Library' and 'Android Support Repository' using Android SDK Manager, re-install and give it a try by relaunching your Android Studio